# Multi-row insert statements using mysqli and bound parameters

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to figure out how to properly achieve multiple row inserts along the format of

```
insert to tbl values (?,?,?), (?,?,?), (?,?,?);
```

The [`mysqli_bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) doc is pretty clear on how to accomplish this for a single row.

From the docs their example looks like:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
```

However I have an multi-dimensional array where each inner element represents a value set, or row, to be inserted.

Comment: This has been addressed on SO before. Please search for it.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSo - The possible duplicate you cited has a solution that looks to be a loop that executes many single row inserts.  This is very inefficient and not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: I would recommend that you try to implement the method in that question and come back with what doesn't work with it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have 2 choices

1. Use the very prepared statement approach to do multiple inserts using once prepared query. Wrapped in a transaction they have to be blazingly fast
2. Create a dynamical call to bind_param which is going to be a pain, an unexpected pain. For some reason mysqli makes dynamical binding overcomplicated.

You will need to merge your array into single one, then create a second array for the references and then call `call_user_func_array()` for this latter approach. Dunno if it worth the mess.